# How to set a label to parse data?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

[image][image][image]How do you set a row of parse data to be equal to label text or button text?  If someone could leave me the code to do this.

The label outlet name is BookName.

I have all of the code written in swift.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like so:

Create a function to fetch the object

```
func getPFObject() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "YourClassName")
    //set your key that you're looking for here
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { ( objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in 
    if error == nil {
        self.BookName.text = objects[0]["foo"] as! String
    }
}
```

And then in `viewDidAppear:` or elsewhere

```
self.getPFObject()
```

As convention, you probably shouldn't start your variable names (like your outlets) with capital letters, it will throw people on SO off! And it's bad style too.

Comment: This doesnt work it saves the object but doesnt set the label to the value that was saved.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, I thought you were asking how to save data to Parse based on the fact that you included your code to save your object. I'll update my answer and you should consider updating your question to more accurately depict what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks so much take your time!

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type '[PFObject]?' I get this error. @pbush25 I but another Pic a the top.

Comment: And all of my other IB actions say to delete IB action @pbush25

Comment: According to what you originally posted your outlet name is `BookName` yet you've tried to set the text of an outlet named `BooName`. As for the subscript error, you need to force unwrap objects like this `objects![0]["foo"]`

Comment: IT is supposed to be like that  @pbush all of the errors that I have from the code you gave me are at the top in a pic.

Comment: Did you fix the things I mentioned?

Comment: Yes all that is left is the IBaction error I put a pic of the error at the top. @pbush25

Comment: I think I have figured everthing out thanks for your help! @pbush25

Comment: What is a class name? @pbush25 Sorry I am new to all of this! :}